# SharePoint 2010 install after SharePoint 2013 install

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation

I have a colleague who is setting up a test farm.  He installed SP 2013 on the server, then decided he didn't want 2013 and then uninstalled 2013, then installed SP 2010.  My understanding was that this is a big no no.  If you have to reinstall SP, you might as well start with a clean server.  Especially if you had a different version of SP.  However, I can't find any concrete documentation from MS on this or whether it is supported or not.  Does anybody have an opinion on this with link to MS's official position on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would go with the clean installation, rebuild the server.

1. SharePoint 2010 [build on .Net 3.5 SP1 and does not support](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751%28v=office.14%29.aspx#section4) .net 4.0 or higher while on other hand SP2013 required .net 4.5,
2. there are many new [pre requisite which required for SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28v=office.15%29.aspx#section4)(should be installed during the installation process) which are not compatible with SP2010.
3. Once you uninstall the SharePoint 2013 still left over on the server which cause the issue with your SP2010. You are coming from New version to old.

I strongly recommend rebuild the server, otherwise clean up properly( uninstall everything, pre-requisite.).

What version of server you are using, Windows 2008 or 2012?

Comment: All SharePoint servers are on a Windows 2008 Server R2 Datacenter SP1

Comment: i would recommend the rebuild of the server is best option & worry free.